# PaperJS: Exporting then Importing an SVG creates extra data (clippath)

Tags: paperjs

I have a drawing tool that needs to be able to export, store and then import a drawing. I am using the following code for exporting:

```
const savedData = scope.project.exportSVG({
     asString: true,
     bounds: scope.view.bounds
});
```

Here is the code for importing:

```
scope.project.importSVG(savedData);
```

If I draw a simple line, console what is imported (the line I just drew), and console what is exported I SHOULD get the same result. Instead this is what I get:

Import:

```
<svg
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="1422"
  height="498"
  viewBox="0,0,1422,498"
>
  <g
    fill="none"
    fill-rule="nonzero"
    stroke="#990000"
    stroke-width="3"
    stroke-linecap="butt"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    stroke-dasharray=""
    stroke-dashoffset="0"
    font-family="none"
    font-weight="none"
    font-size="none"
    text-anchor="none"
    style="mix-blend-mode: normal"
  >
    <path
      d="M426,41l4,5l4,7l4,5l2,4l3,6l3,5l3,4l2,4l3,3l1,4l1,1l1,4l2,2l1,2l2,4l1,1l1,3l2,2l1,1v1"
      style="mix-blend-mode: destination-over"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Export:

```
<svg
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="1422"
  height="498"
  viewBox="0,0,1422,498"
>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-1">
      <rect
        x="0"
        y="0"
        width="1422"
        height="498"
        stroke="none"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g
    fill="none"
    fill-rule="nonzero"
    stroke="none"
    stroke-width="none"
    stroke-linecap="butt"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    stroke-dasharray=""
    stroke-dashoffset="0"
    font-family="none"
    font-weight="none"
    font-size="none"
    text-anchor="none"
    style="mix-blend-mode: normal"
  >
    <g clip-path="url(#clip-1)">
      <g stroke="#990000" stroke-width="3">
        <path
          d="M426,41l4,5l4,7l4,5l2,4l3,6l3,5l3,4l2,4l3,3l1,4l1,1l1,4l2,2l1,2l2,4l1,1l1,3l2,2l1,1v1"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The defs and clippath are causing layering issues when adding more to the loaded drawing. Why is it converting my svg this way? Where is that clippath coming from? Is there a property I am missing?

Comment: Given your use case, maybe you would be better storing your drawings as JSON, which should not have this kind of side effects: http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#exportjson

Comment: I did wind up using exportJSON/importJSON. Apparently there is a known issue on importSVG that was never resolved:
https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1296